# How to translate Enum string in django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, translation

So I have a model that has a status field, for that I've created an `Enum` class, like that:

```
class Status(Enum):
    PENDING_APPROVAL = "PENDING-APPROVAL"
    PLANNED = "PLANNED"
    APPROVED = "APPROVED"
    CHANGED_PLAN = "CHANGED-PLAN"
    COMPLETED = "COMPLETED"
    CANCELED = "CANCELED"
```

And then added this class as a choice for the model:

```
status = models.CharField(
        choices=[(tag.value, tag.name) for tag in Status],
        max_length=20,
        verbose_name=pgettext("Order", "Status"),
        default=Status.PENDING_APPROVAL.value,
    )
```

All works fine, but the problem is that once I click on my dropdown to pick a choice from my `Enum` class, I want for my choices to be translated to the other language of my site.

I cannot find how to translate my `Enum`'s class choices to the language that I need.

Comment: Where are you displaying this? Django admin or a custom view? In both cases paste your code

Comment: I'm using it in admin and in my view. View is simply rendered by a ModelForm where I declare my Model an fields, simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Use standard [models.TextChoices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types) which can optionally accepts translation too:

```python
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class Status(models.TextChoices):
    APPROVED = 'APPROVED', _('Approved')
    CANCELED = 'CANCELED', _('Canceled')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to support multiple languages, take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/translation/

If you want to get the human-readable version of these enum values, there is a prebuilt function in Django called `get_[fieldname]_display()` that returns the enum value rather than the key.